# how to collect a list of new IDs between two successive dates with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing a groupby over a week column in a PYSPARK dataframe and collecting new different IDs between two sucessive weeks number.

I tried doing a *groupby* over week column then aggregating the *collect_set* method on the dataframe to get all the available IDs, then i compared the lists one by one to get the different ID between two successive lists by week number as below:

**Input** :

| Week | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ID_1 |
| 1 | ID_2 |
| 1 | ID_3 |
| 2 | ID_1 |
| 2 | ID_4 |
| 2 | ID_5 |
| 3 | ID_6 |

**OUTPUT**:

| Week | ID_List | diff_list | new_different_ID_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID_1, ID_2,ID_3 | ID_1, ID_2, ID_3 | - |
| 2 | ID_1, ID_4, ID_5 | ID_4, ID_5 | 2 |
| 3 | ID_2, ID_6 | ID_6 | 1 |

The probleme here is that  as the huge number of IDs i have in my case (more than 9 million ID) the spark session is being killed due to an Out of Memory Error i think (*Error 500*)!

Is there any other solution to get the list of new different IDs beetween two successive weeks with PYSPARK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to scale, you need to aggregate by the ID instead, without collecting any results. Try the following approach:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "ID_1"), (1, "ID_2"), (1, "ID_3"),
                              (2, "ID_1"), (2, "ID_4"), (2, "ID_5"),
                              (3, "ID_6")], ["Week", "ID"])

win = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('Week')

agg_data = (
  data
  .withColumn("prevWeek", F.lag("Week", offset=1).over(win))
  .withColumn("isInPrevWeek", 
              F.col("prevWeek").isNotNull() & ((F.col("Week") - F.col("prevWeek")) == 1))
  .filter(~F.col("isInPrevWeek"))
  .groupBy("Week")
  .agg(F.count("*").alias("newIDs"),
       F.array_sort(F.collect_list("ID")).alias("showNewIDs"))  # Remove in production
  .orderBy("Week")
)

agg_data.show()
```

First, the function `lag` creates a new column with the previous Week using a Window function which allows to consider each ID individually (partition) and sorts the weeks chronologically. That scales well because the Spark tasks are made of group of IDs.

Then, `isInPrevWeek` checks if the ID was indeed in the previous week. If so, the record is filtered out. Now, you just need to count the remining IDs by week.

```
+----+------+------------------+
|Week|newIDs|        showNewIDs|
+----+------+------------------+
|   1|     3|[ID_1, ID_2, ID_3]|
|   2|     2|      [ID_4, ID_5]|
|   3|     1|            [ID_6]|
+----+------+------------------+
```

Note that the snippet collects the IDs just for illustrative purposes but that is not required for the computation.