# Count unique ids between two consecutive dates that are values of a column in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DF, with ID and Date column, looking like this.

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2 | 2021-10-01 |
| 1 | 2021-10-02 |
| 3 | 2021-10-02 |

I want to count the number of unique IDs that did not exist in the date one day before. So, here the result would be 1 as there is only one new unique ID in 2021-10-02.

| ID | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 | - |
| 2 | 2021-10-01 | - |
| 1 | 2021-10-02 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-10-02 | 1 |

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67121704/how-to-collect-a-list-of-new-ids-between-two-successive-dates-with-pyspark) solution but it does not work on date type value. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Your example is somehow inconsistent, because on 2021-10-01 both IDs 1 and 2 were "new".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid a self-join (e.g. for performance reasons), you could work with Window functions:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row, Window
import datetime

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(ID=1, date=datetime.date(2021,10,1)),
    Row(ID=2, date=datetime.date(2021,10,1)),
    Row(ID=1, date=datetime.date(2021,10,2)),
    Row(ID=2, date=datetime.date(2021,10,2)),
    Row(ID=1, date=datetime.date(2021,10,3)),
    Row(ID=3, date=datetime.date(2021,10,3)),
])
```

First add the number of days since an ID was last seen (will be `None` if it never appeared before)

```py
df = df.withColumn('days_since_last_occurrence', F.datediff('date', F.lag('date').over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('date'))))
```

Second, we add a column marking rows where this number of days is not 1. We add a 1 into this column so that we can later sum over this column to count the rows

```py
df = df.withColumn('is_new', F.when(F.col('days_since_last_occurrence') == 1, None).otherwise(1))
```

Now we do the sum of all rows with the same date and then remove the column we do not require anymore:

```py
(
    df
    .withColumn('count', F.sum('is_new').over(Window.partitionBy('date'))) # sum over all rows with the same date
    .drop('is_new', 'days_since_last_occurrence')
    .sort('date', 'ID')
    .show()
)
# Output:
+---+----------+-----+
| ID|      date|count|
+---+----------+-----+
|  1|2021-10-01|    2|
|  2|2021-10-01|    2|
|  1|2021-10-02| null|
|  2|2021-10-02| null|
|  1|2021-10-03|    1|
|  3|2021-10-03|    1|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Comment: I changed my answer to follow the lines of the post linked by the OP

Comment: Hi Til,
Thank you very much. It works! Can you please add comments to what each line is doing. :)

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat: I extended my answer and hope the code is clearer now :)

Answer (score 0):

Take out the id list of the current day and the previous day, and then get the size of the difference between the two to get the final result.

Update to a solution to eliminate `join`.

```
df = df.select('date', F.expr('collect_set(id) over (partition by date) as id_arr')).dropDuplicates() \
    .select('*', F.expr('size(array_except(id_arr, lag(id_arr,1,id_arr) over (order by date))) as count')) \
    .select(F.explode('id_arr').alias('id'), 'date', 'count')
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: I guess, this would work, but a self-join is often problematic in Spark and better avoided.